# how to take snapshot of google map with polyline and openInfoWindowHtml

Tags: javascript

I'm working on functionality to take snapshot of  google map with polylines and open popup window on polyline click on google map.
The snapshot of google map with polylines is working 
but it will not able to take snapshot open popup window on polyline.
polyline are showing on sanpshot picture but info window are not showing .
Here is code to take snapshot.

This code is to initialize the code control on javascript onload :

```
     var snapShotControlOptions = { hidden: true };
                snapShotControlOptions.buttonLabelHtml="<snap id='snap' style='display:none' >snap</span>"
                snapShotControl = new SnapShotControl(snapShotControlOptions);
                map.addControl(snapShotControl);
```

here is the method take snap to take the sanp shot of google map .

```
        function takeSnap() {

            //static map size
            var sizeStr = "640x640";
            var imgSize = "";
            if (sizeStr != "") {
                var sizeArray = sizeStr.split("x");
                imgSize = new GSize(sizeArray[0], sizeArray[1]);
            }
            snapShotControl.setMapSize(imgSize);
            var format = "jpg";
            snapShotControl.setFormat(format);

            var url = snapShotControl.getImage();
            //            document.getElementById("snapshot_canvas").src = url;
            SaveImage(url);

            //         
        }

//this will add polyline overlay to draw line on google map with different color of polyline on google map .

  var polyline = directionsArray[num].getPolyline();
                polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: streetColor, weight: 3, opacity: 0.7 });
                polyline.ssColor=streetColor;                
                map.addOverlay(polyline);


///this code will open the pop info window on polyline those polyline created on google map
```

and problem is their these pop window not included on sanpshot when i take sanpshot of google map.

```
  var MousePoint = "";
                var marker;
                GEvent.addListener(map, "mousemove", function (point) {
                    MousePoint = new GLatLng(point.lat(), point.lng());

                });

                GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function () {                   
                    map.openInfoWindowHtml(MousePoint, headMarkerHtml);                   
                });
                GEvent.addListener(polyline, "mouseout", function () {
                    // map.closeInfoWindow();
                });
```

can you please tell who i pass popup window in polyline overlay .

i have use javascript file snapshotcontrol.js to take the snapshot.

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle script? I can help you but ı should see your code on runtime

Answer (score 0):

from the snapshotcontrol source

> This library makes it easy to generate an image "snapshot" of your
>   interactive map, using the Google Static Maps API.

Static maps doesn't support info windows or anything like adding custom text to the map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index

You could draw the map on a canvas within the browser then
draw the info window on top of that using this http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
and then download the canvas content