# Take screenshot of google map

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to take snapshot of google map with polyline and openInfoWindowHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946891/how-to-take-snapshot-of-google-map-with-polyline-and-openinfowindowhtml)

I'm working on functionality to take snapshot of google map with polyline and info window popup on map.

i have created functionality to take snapshot of google map with polylines is working 
but it will not able to take snapshot open popup window on polyline.

polyline are showing on sanpshot picture but info window are not showing .

can u plz explain who i can do this ?

Comment: why are you repeating your own question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946891/how-to-take-snapshot-of-google-map-with-polyline-and-openinfowindowhtml

Comment: i,m not repeating my question my previous post is to need help in existing functionality. this post is for how i can do this in javascript.